# MoveToElement doesn't work to mouse hover and hold the click on an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Following is the sample HTML code of the page:

[image]

I'm trying to mouse hover on the element with following xpath:

```
WebElement Bar1 = dvr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='barModel']/div[@class='model']/canvas[@class='segment']")));
```

Following is the code

```
act = new Action (driver);
act.moveToElement(Bar1).build().perform();
act.clickAndHold();
```

My objective is to drag the element. Running the above code doesn't give any error but there is no visible interaction on the page. I am able to do this task using Robot class but just curious to make it happen using Action class.

Comment: I don't suppose you can link the page or a similar page that we can see?

Comment: Yeah I can't do that because of privacy reasons. Although I can paste any other HTML snippet you want.

Comment: The canvas tag is an HTML canvas and could have all kinds of stuff displayed within it. Are you trying to grab something inside it or the whole thing? Generally clicks(), etc go for the center of the element and this canvas you are talking about is pretty large... 467x43. You may have to use one of the offset methods to hone in on what you want. Can you post a screenshot of the canvas element and what you are trying to do?

Comment: The element is a rectangular bar. I'm trying to click on it's right outer edge of it because it can be dragged only from this point. I tried using act.moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset), after getting the coordinates from ele.getLocation().getX(); and ele.getLocation().getY(); but the coordinates obtained are not correct.
My first thought was that I'm facing this trouble because it's a canvas but it turns out the problem is for any other element on the page

Answer (score 0):

You didn't performed clickAndHold action:

```
act = new Action (driver);
act.moveToElement(Bar1).build().perform();
act.clickAndHold().perform();
```

If you want to drag and drop element you can just use build-in function:

```
act.dragAndDrop(movedElement, targetElement).perform();
```

Comment: I tried doing that as well but there is no mouse action visible on screen.

The reason I can't use dragAndDrop method is because only a section of the element is draggable. Thus first, I have to mouse hover on that section and then drag it

Comment: Are you sure there is visible action when you do it manually? Be sure you not move mouse, only "clickAndHold" when you check it manually

Comment: Yes I can mouse hover to the draggable part of the element (the mouse cursor changes at this point), click and hold and then drag
I have also tried using
act.moveToElement(toElement, xOffset, yOffset)
but even then mouse hover doesn't work. The X and Y coordinates were obtained by using element.getLocation().getX(); and element.getLocation().getY();

Comment: notice that you dont see cursor while test script is running, so you cant see the cursor change. I suggest you to try this code, you will see if element move: http://pastebin.com/ui2A2s8i

Comment: Tried this but mouse didn't move the least. I also did elementFarfromBar1.click(); just an additional step for verification. It was clicked but mouse didn't hover over that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptExecutor` to perform `mouseover` as like below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dvr;
js.executeScript("var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');clickEvent.initEvent('mouseover', true, true); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);", Bar1);
```

By using above `Java Script` you can perform `mouseover`. Now you can use `dragAndDrop` to move element as below :-

```
Actions action = new Actions(dvr)
action.dragAndDrop(sourceElement, destinationElement).build().perform()
```

Hope it will help you...:)